# jQuery passing id to hidden form input

Tags: jquery, forms, input, tabs

I found this code on stackoverflow to send an active tab to a input hidden form value, which works so far:

```
$('#weiter').on('click', function(){
$('#starterpaket').val($('#tabs-1 li').index('.active'));
alert($('#starterpaket').val());
})
```

What I want is the ID of the active tab and my tries didnt work .. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this $('#starterpaket').val($('#tabs-1 li.active').attr('id'));

Comment: **Thanks a lot!!**